# Name Value Lookup List where Name is from data source

Tags: fieldtype

Is it possible in Sitecore 7.5 to bind all the names in a Name Value Lookup to a datasource?

For example the name will be represented as a dropdown list.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible out of the box, you will need to create a custom field in order to achieve this.

I've previously blogged about a custom [Name Value Lookup field](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/custom-sitecore-field-for-storing-keyvalue-data-with-lookups/), which allows the key portion of the list to be datasource driven and only selectable from a dropdown list.

[image: Custom Name Value field]

All the code is available in this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jammykam/de0dabe2ac4612fe649e), but essentially:

- Create a new custom field that inherits from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.NameLookupValue`
- Override the `OnLoad` method (inherited from base of above), and provide your own implementations of `LoadValue()` and `BuildControl()`.
- The original `LoadValue()` code has a regex validation in there which disallows dashes (i.e. not good for GUIDs)
- The `BuildControl()` method calls through to generate the required markup of your control. In the case of this custom field, [line 112](https://gist.github.com/jammykam/de0dabe2ac4612fe649e#file-namelookuplist-L112) is where the call is made to get the collection of items based on the datasource value and then build the dropdown list. Modify the logic and markup as required.

There is also [a more recent post](https://pratiksatikunvar.wordpress.com/2018/08/11/namelookuplist-field-with-query-and-dynamic-item-field-sources/) that builds on the above and allows use of Datasource queries to resolve the list, if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. But I've used a custom field type many times that sort of does what you ask.

It's called [Unbound Droplist](https://github.com/getfishtank/Sitecore-UnboundDroplist).

It basically allows you to set a pipe delimited string as values in a droplist. Like `red|white|orange`. It's not quite what you ask, but I would need to know more about what you're trying to accomplish to narrow an answer down further.